# Angular Material table filter with nested object

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two Arrays in my object which leads to the case, that I can actually filter for one Array, but not the second one.

This is my filter predicate which works fine for the district array, but not for the array propertyType. Does someone has an idea how I filter for the second array too?

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string)  => {
  const accumulator = (currentTerm, key) => {
    return key === 'district' ? currentTerm + data.district.name : currentTerm + data[key];
  };
  const dataStr = Object.keys(data).reduce(accumulator, '').toLowerCase();
  // Transform the filter by converting it to lowercase and removing whitespace.
  const transformedFilter = filter.trim().toLowerCase();
  return dataStr.indexOf(transformedFilter) !== -1;
};
```

Interface

```
export interface Property {
   city: string;
   description: string;
   district: District; <-- here
   efficiencyRating: EfficiencyRating; <-- here
   houseno: string;
   id: number;
   name: string;
   propertyType: PropertyType; <-- here 
}
```

Comment: [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method's reducer function first parameter is accumulator, not current term. The function is doing the job but I suggest changing the variable name to avoid confusion. Also, do you want to search just the keys of `propertyType` array?

Comment: According to your explanation, you seem to want the filter to work when there are arrays in the object values (the default `filterPredicate` already covers this case), but the `filterPredicate` you've posted above makes it seem like the explanation is not exactly right. Please clarify your question by adding a sample of your data.

Comment: Sorry, I explained it wrong! Rough day :D So I have multiple objects in by interface, not arrays. I updated my question.

Comment: Try to stringify your nested objects with `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Comment: This helped, thank you JuNe! Changed the following to get it working:         _return key === 'propertyType' ? currentTerm + JSON.stringify(data) : currentTerm + data[key];_

Comment: @mapof - By doing `JSON.stringify(data)` you are searching the whole object which I think isn't what you want. If you do that your `filter` string will also search the keys `city`, `description` etc.